# How do I assign a value to textbox when I click on a row in obout grid?

Tags: jquery, obout

I'm working on about grid and when I click on a row of it the text box controls in a panel under the grid have to fill with the selected row values. I'm doing this on the client side and using onClientSelect property of grid view. I'm getting the values when I click on the row but couldn't assign them to controls. Please look the code and let me know

```
<%@ Register Assembly="obout_Grid_NET" Namespace="Obout.Grid" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="obout_Interface" Namespace="Obout.Interface" TagPrefix="cc2" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="igg" Namespace="HR" Assembly="HR" %>



<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function OnRecordFillPanel(arrSelectedRecords) {
         for (var i = 0; i < arrSelectedRecords.length; i++) {
             var record = arrSelectedRecords[i];
             $("#ernType").text = record.EARNCDE;//**problem comes here cannot assign value to textbox.**

         }

}
function addNewRec() {
    $('#ernType').val('');//**and also cannot clear the value here**
}
  </script>

 <div >
 <div>
 <ISS:ISSOGrid ID="grd_EarningCodeTable" runat="server" Width="100%" OnClientSelect="OnRecordFillPanel" 
 AllowMultiRecordSelection="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false">  
  <Columns>
  <cc1:Column ID="col_ErnType" DataField="EARNCDE" HeaderText="Earning Code" runat="server"
              HeaderAlign="Left" Align="Left" Width="20%" />
  <cc1:Column ID="col_Desc" DataField="DESCRIPTION" HeaderText="Description" runat="server"
              HeaderAlign="Left" Align="Left" Width="25%" />

   </ISS:ISSOGrid>
   </div>

    <div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_details" runat="server" Height="214px">
    <div id="Div1" class = "showdetails" visible = "true" runat ="server" style="padding : 20px;">

      <div style ="padding: 6px; width: 882px;">
          <label>Earnings Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
          <asp:TextBox ID = "ernType"  runat ="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>
       <div style ="padding: 6px; width: 467px;">
          <label>Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
          <asp:TextBox ID = "desc" runat ="server" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>

      <div style ="padding: 6px;">

              <asp:Button ID="btn_new" runat="server" Text="New" OnClientClick="javascript:addNewRec();" />
          </asp:Panel>
      </div>

      </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </div>


</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using an `id` in the way you want to be using a `class`. I am assuming that `arrSelectedRecords` has multiple entries which is why you use the for loop, and  that looks like it may be the reason this is failing.

### There should only be 1 unique ID per webpage!

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arrSelectedRecords.length; i++) {
     var record = arrSelectedRecords[i];
     $(".ernType").val(record.EARNCDE);//**problem comes here cannot assign value to textbox.**

 }
```

above is how the for loop should look. I may be wrong in interpreting your question, but I believe that may be the issue. So you will have to change everything that has `id="ernType"` to `class="ernType"`.

Although, I am 90% guessing here what you want. It would be helpful if you would provide some more information.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this without using for loop..I mean can the function OnRecordFillPanel be written in other way

Comment: You gotta give me some more info on what you are trying to achieve. An example would be helpful. What are you trying to do with each `EARNCDE` from the `arrSelectedRecords` entries

Comment: @user3154990 just to show you a quick example of how id's work differently than classes look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/KEtJ8/

Comment: I'll be just displaying that erncde in the text box, for example if the ern code is FGG and when I click on the row the text box should be populated by FGG smoething like this

Comment: something like this $("#ernType").text=$("#col_ErnType").val("EARNCDE");

Comment: @user3154990 Well, you also probably have to wrap your entire script in `$(document).ready(function(){ //code });`

Comment: I figured out my self, just replaced $(".ernType").val(record.EARNCDE); with  $("[id$=ernType]").val(record.EARNCDE); the problem was object for textbox is not being created. Thanks for your precious time and answers